# Excel VBA Output to PDF Zoom %

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

Is there a way to control the zoom % on the PDF when it is printed via a macro?  I have zoomed in on the spreadsheet at 100% but the PDF always shows at 79.3% and it's really hard to see.  If it is zoomed in at 200%, it shows perfectly fine on the PDF.  I would normally ignore this aspect and just tell the user to zoom in but it's for the CEO and, ya know.

Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Sel_Manager As String
'Specify headers to be repeated at the top
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$5:$10"
        .PrintTitleColumns = "$B:$M"
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With

'Manager selection through simple Inputbox
 Sel_Manager = ComboBox1
'Insert autofilter for worksheet
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
'Select manager defined in inputbox
ActiveSheet.Range("B10", Range("M10").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sel_Manager
ActiveSheet.Range("B10", Range("M10").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="A"
 'Select range to be printed and specify manager in filename
ActiveSheet.Range("B10", Range("M10").End(xlDown)).Select

Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
Sel_Manager + ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you end the sub, can you add those lines to your code please.

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = False
        '.PrintArea = Worksheets(ReportWsName).UsedRange
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        '.FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

Comment: For the print area, it will automatically adjust based on the autofilter, how would I adjust it for that?  Thank you for your help so far!